# Are custom slot values requred in Alexa Skill?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Are custom slot values required?

Let's assume that I have web application with `Items` in database.

In alexa skill user can say: "tell me about `${item.name}`".

I have custom slot `LIST_OF_ITEMS` that looks like:

> Value: Item Box ID:5
>
> Value: React JS book ID: 12

Are slot values requred? Can I just get what user said and search by this name using my web application API?

```
var item = slots.items.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].values[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The slot values you provide give the Alexa engine a 'hint' as to what to expect, even if you expect to receive other values besides those that you list.